# Using Wallis' product to derive $\sqrt\pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Recall Wallis' product:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\frac{2}{1}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{6}{5}\cdots\frac{2n}{2n-1}\cdot\frac{2n}{2n+1}\Big)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

We have to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n!)^22^{2n}}{(2n)!\sqrt n}=\sqrt\pi$$

The hint I got was to use $$P_n=\frac{(n!)^42^{4n}}{[(2n)!]^2(2n+1)}$$
which is just simply the inside of the limit in Wallis' product, multiplied and divided by $2\cdot2\cdot4\cdot4\cdots(2n)\cdot(2n)$ alternatively. How do I use $P_n$ to derive $\sqrt\pi\:$?

Comment: I think, you should need Stirling formula.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah that comes later, so I can't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, $P_n \to \frac{\pi}{2}$ since it's the inside of limit of the L.H.S of the Wallis Product Formula multiplied by $1$.  Since continuous maps preserve limits, this implies $\sqrt{2P_n} \to \sqrt{\pi} $ and note that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{2P_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{2}(n!)^2 2^{2n}}{(2n)!\sqrt{2n+1 }} \\ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n!)^22^{2n}}{(2n)!\sqrt{n+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}} \\ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n!)^22^{2n}}{(2n)! \sqrt{n}}$$

Where the last equality was got by translation invariance.

Comment: I'm actually quite puzzled that you could have noticed that $P_n$ was the inside limit of the Wallis Product Formula multiplied by $1$ in a certain way but still be confused on how to answer this question.

Comment: That was part of the hint, I just didn't want to write out the whole thing. I have two questions

Comment: First, how did you multiply and take the square root knowing that they're limits?

Comment: Second, how did you go from the first limit to the second?

Comment: I edited the answer adding mildly more detail.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't understand how you're able to go from $P_n\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\sqrt {2P_n} \rightarrow \sqrt\pi$. So, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=L/c$ can be rewritten as $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt {cf(x)}=\sqrt L$ if its a continuous map?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L/c$ implies that $ lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{cf(x)} = \sqrt{L}$  because multiplication by $c$ and taking square roots are continuous maps.

Comment: You're right! I forgot that it's a basic property of limits which I proved a while back ago. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Try to internalize those properties about limits.  I guess I forget that new students may not use his fact so immediately

Comment: @DionelJaime Hi. I know it's been more than a year but I don't understand why  $$lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{2}(n!)^2 2^{2n}}{(2n)!\sqrt{2n+1 }} \\ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n!)^22^{2n}}{(2n)!\sqrt{n+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}} \\$$. what algebraic manipulation did you use to get $\frac{\sqrt{2}(n!)^2 2^{2n}}{(2n)!\sqrt{2n+1 }} = \frac{(n!)^22^{2n}}{(2n)!\sqrt{n+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}} $ ?